# How to make NDK compile more "Intelligent" when .mk file is modified?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using NDK-r7 on my Android project. I found if `Android.mk` or `Application.mk` was modified, NDK will compile WHOLE project again.

Since I'm using a shell script to copy .mk files with different environments, I found even copied .mk files with exactly same contents will also cause NDK to compile WHOLE project, which wastes lots of time.

For example, I have a `Application.mk` file with content `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)`, then I use `cp Application2.mk Application.mk` (they have same contents), NDK will build whole cpp files again.

Is that any way to avoid this, or to make NDK compile more "Intelligent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way. You can only make your project smarter.

e.g.

- split it in subproject with static libs. (.a)
- move out bullet physics into libs or other subproject that do not use your main code.